# Create new local calendar in android pre ICS

Tags: android, calendar

I have been struggelig for weeks on this, so now I hope someone here can give me some clarity.

The project I'm working on(pre ICS) includes logging on to my company's server, getting my future work schedule and store this on my phone in a seperate calendar. This calendar should them be viewable in all the major calendar apps (Jorte, Business Calendar, Smooth Calendar ++).
I got the schedule parsed and stored on the phone in an SQLite database. But my struggle is getting from there to create a seperate local calendar and store all the events there. I assumed I had to create an account for this (not to mess up any other account on the phone. That worked well with the code:

```
AccountManager man = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account acc = new Account("myCalendar", "com.lumabyte.mycalendar");
```

But I thought creating a calendar on that account would be quite easy with:

```
ContentValues calendar = new ContentValues();
calendar.put("_sync_account", "myCalendar"); // My account
calendar.put("_sync_account_type","com.lumabyte.mycalendar"); 
calendar.put("name", "myCalendar");
calendar.put("displayName", "myCalendar");
calendar.put("hidden",0);
calendar.put("color",0xFF008080);
calendar.put("access_level", 700);
calendar.put("sync_events", 1);
calendar.put("timezone", "Europe/Paris");
calendar.put("ownerAccount", sync_account);
Uri calendarUri = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase() + "calendars");
this.getContentResolver().insert(calendarUri, calendar);
```

The function getCalendarUriBase():

```
private String getCalendarUriBase() {

    String calendarUriBase = null;
    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    try {
        managedCursor = this.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // eat
    }

    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        try {
            managedCursor = this.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // eat
        }

        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
        }

    }

    managedCursor.close();

    return calendarUriBase;
}
```

The manifest includes:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAMAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR">
```

and my authenticator.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:accountType="com.lumabyte.mycalendar"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/authenticator_label"
/>
```

I do not get any error messages, but only the account is created, and not the calendar. Is there a small error in the code, or have I misunderstood the whole concept. I know there is no API pre ICS, and that there is risks involved. But I need it done anyway. Prefeably stable on as many phones as possible. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I'll work with ICS later as I understand they now have i public API for that.

r

Answer (score 2):

hiii rudder............. I have add a calender in 2.3.6 using the following code after lot of R&D.........

```
ContentValues calendar=new ContentValues();
Uri calendarUri =Uri.parse(getBaseCalUri() + "/calendars");

calendar.put("_sync_account", "Test1");
calendar.put("_sync_account_type", "LOCAL");

    calendar.put("name", "CalenTest");
    calendar.put("displayName", "calDispName");
    calendar.put("color", 0xFF008080);
    calendar.put("access_level", 700);
    calendar.put("ownerAccount", true);
    calendar.put("sync_events", 1);

    calendarUri = calendarUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("_sync_account", "Test1")
        .appendQueryParameter("_sync_account_type", "LOCAL")  
        .build();
    Uri result = getContentResolver().insert(calendarUri, calendar);
```

and my getBaseCalUri() is

```
private Uri getBaseCalUri(){
        Class<?> calendarProviderClass;
        Field uriField;
        Uri calendarUri=null;
        try {
            calendarProviderClass = Class.forName("android.provider.Calendar");
            uriField = calendarProviderClass.getField("CONTENT_URI");
            calendarUri = (Uri) uriField.get(null);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return calendarUri;
    }
```

try this....

Answer (score 0):

Just add a records in the calendar.db 
/data/data/com.android.providers.calendar/databases/calendar.db
as 
sqlite3 calendar.db "insert into Calendars (_id,name,displayName,access_level) values (0,'Local','MyCal',700)"

Answer (score -2):

This is a good way that I tried, I hope it helps:

/**
 * Add a calendar event.
 */

```
private void addCalendarEvent(){
                    Context context = getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", stTime);
            intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);
            intent.putExtra("eventLocation", place);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
            intent.putExtra("endTime", enTime);
            intent.putExtra("title", category);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Please the question was about **local calendar creation**